# What's PHP info or PHP setting requirement to run SoapClient in PHP?

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I began desperate enough. I have a web service, it's connected pretty well in my localhost, i have same allow_url_fopen=Off, extensions=php_openssl.dll enabled but the one on the new server couldn't connect to SoapClient and still give this error :

> SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load
>   from 'https://xxx.xxx.xxx/wssupport/xxxx.asmx?wsdl' : failed to load
>   external entity "https://xxx.xxx.xxx/wssupport/xxxx.asmx?wsdl" in
>   /home/report/public_html/test.php:4 Stack trace: #0
>   /home/report/public_html/test.php(4):
>   SoapClient->SoapClient('https://xxx...', Array) #1 {main}

The web service been run through many apps, and the server been online hosting several website so it's 100% connected to internet so it should have nothing wrong.
My apache and php version :

> Apache/2.4.12 and PHP/5.5.22

my code if necessary :

```
<?php
$wsurl="https://xxx.xxx.xxx/xxx/xxx.asmx?wsdl";
    try {
        $client = new SoapClient($wsurl,array('trace' => 1, 'exception' => 0, 'cache_wsdl' => 0));
        $token=($client->SLogin(array("username"=>'test', "password" =>'test',"appcode"=>'test',"appversion"=>'test'))->SLoginResult);
        echo $token;
    } catch (SoapFault $exception) {
        echo $exception;
    }
?>
```

I want to know what're actually all the settings and requirement in PHP to call SoapClient ?

Comment: You can hit the same WSDL in soap ui with those credentials without issue? The fact that you're getting the soap error means you've got things installed correctly but you're having issues retrieving that resource.

Comment: yes i can connect normally without any issue on my localhost or other apps but not the one with this server.. yet

Comment: it maybe about httpS, your server can't get the certificate via opensll library try this command line at your server:
`wget "https://xxx.xxx.xxx/xxx/xxx.asmx?wsdl"`

Comment: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx|111.111.111.111|:443... failed: No route to host. ? so this mean. gonna google it out for abit thanks for help !